# How to force itemrenderer to overlap display content of neighbour itemrenderers

Tags: list, apache-flex, itemrenderer, flex-spark

I have a spark List with horizontal layout and custom ItemRenderer.

Each ItemRenderer has a width=80px. But it may contain graphic objects (s:Rect for example) with more than 80px width.

After compiling it looks like "overflow:hidden". But i need something like "overflow:visible" for my renderers and to see full size of my rectangles and other objects.

How to prevent the cutting of overflowed width and to display whole objects with overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

Set `clipAndEnableScrolling=false` on the `itemRenderer`.

Comment: It was my mistake when i wrote that i have vertical layout. I have horizontal layout.  For this situation "clipAndEnableScrolling=false" allows to display full content of only the last item in List. Content of each previous itemrenderer is overlapped by next neighbour itemrenderer area.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use a DataGroup, which allows you to use any layout you please.